# Clip or cut sound files

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, ios6

Is there a method to cut the audio files in objective c programatically. Files with extension such as mp3, caf, wav etc. Can any one please help me how to find one. I have googled it for days but still cant find any suitable solution. Any help is appreciated. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to cut the waveform or the binary file?

Comment: its waveform that we want to cut

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clip the waveform, the easiest way to do that is to perform a clipping on each sample. Pseudocode:

```
Sample clipSample(Sample sample) {
  if(abs(sample) > clipLimit) {
    return sign(sample) * clipLimit
  } else {
    return sample
  }
}
```

This is a simple peak clipper. Usually this kind of clipping produces a high amount of unpleasant distortion. If you want to avoid that you should search for either a decent compressor or a decent limiter.

Comment: Its not about the waveform pattern that i specified its about the sound wave not the wave form

Comment: Do you mean something like substring(start, stop)? I.e. slicing?

Comment: i just want to cut or clip a specified sound file

Comment: What do you mean by "clip or cut"? Can you give an example?